# $stateProvider loading service object is not defined

Tags: angularjs

I have a service:

```
      angular.module('TestApp')
      .service('Test', ['$http', '$localStorage', function($http, $localStorage) {
        var baseUrl = "http://test.com";

        return {
            tests: function(success, error) {
                $http.get(baseUrl + '/tests').success(success).error(error)
            }
        } 
      }]);
```

I have a controller:

```
angular.module('TestApp')
  .controller('TestController',  ['$rootScope', '$scope', Test, function($rootScope, $scope, Test) {

    Merchant.terminal(function(res) {
        $scope.tests= res;
    }, function() {
        $rootScope.error = 'Failed to fetch details';
    }); 
 }]);
```

Then in the app.js I use resolve to get the files:

```
$stateProvider.state('test', {
           url: "/test", 
           templateUrl: "views/test.html",
           data: {pageTitle: 'Test Search'},
           controller: "TestController",
           resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        name: 'TestApp',
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', 
                        files: [
                            'scripts/controllers/TestController.js',
                            'scripts/services/testService.js',
                        ] 
                    });
                }]
            }
       });
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Test is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put service file before controller

```
'scripts/services/testService.js',
'scripts/controllers/TestController.js'
```

Injector should be a string

```
['$rootScope', '$scope', 'Test', function
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an '' while name Service in your controller , since it is a string.

**From**

```
angular.module('TestApp')
  .controller('TestController',  ['$rootScope', '$scope', Test, function($rootScope, $scope, Test)
```

**To**

```
angular.module('TestApp')
  .controller('TestController',  ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'Test', function($rootScope, $scope, Test)
```

Also Put the service up the order before you load the controller

```
'scripts/services/testService.js'
'scripts/controllers/TestController.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your controller definition from:

```
angular.module('TestApp')
   .controller('TestController',  ['$rootScope', '$scope', Test,
function($rootScope, $scope, Test) { ... }
```

to:

```
angular.module('TestApp')
   .controller('TestController',  ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'Test',
function($rootScope, $scope, Test) { ... }
```

Note the 'Test' in the list of dep injections...

Comment: lol, so I will give a up-vote for all and a tick for the earliest and complete answer.